# Can the complement of a projective variety be isomorphic to an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let's say I have a Projective variety and take its complement. This should be open, since the variety is closed. Now is it possible for this to be isomorphic to an affine variety? Since affine varieties are closed, but the complement described above is open, and morphisms are continuous, shouldn't closed sets only map to closed sets in an isomorphism?

Comment: What do you mean by "affine varieties are closed"?  In which space?  Certainly not as quasiprojective varieties in that projective space.

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism between two varieties is just an isomorphism between those varieties, not between their ambient spaces.  So if you have an open subvariety $U\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ and a closed subvariety $C\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n$, an isomorphism between $U$ and $C$ is just a morphism $U\to C$, not a morphism $\mathbb{P}^n\to\mathbb{A}^n$.  So, there is no reason that such an isomorphism would force $C$ to be open in $\mathbb{A}^n$ or $U$ to be closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

For example, note that for any $n$, $\mathbb{A}^n$ is the complement of the hyperplane $H$ at infinity in $\mathbb{P}^n$.  So, $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$ even though $\mathbb{A}^n$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$ but $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus H$ is not closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Ok, I see. How does this relate to coordinate rings? For example, if there is an isomorphism between a quasi-projective variety like ^2/{0,0} to an affine variety, is there also an isomorphism between their respective coordinate rings?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean by "coordinate ring"--usually that's defined only for affine varieties.  But if you mean the ring of regular functions, then yes, an isomorphism between two varieties induces an isomorphism between their rings of regular functions.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused: Can there be an isomorphism between something that is affine and something that is not affine?

Comment: That depends what you mean by "affine".  It is possible to have an isomorphism between a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^n$ and a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^m$ that is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\subset\mathbb P^n$ be a closed, irreducible projective subvariety and $U=\mathbb P^n\setminus X$ its open complement. Then:

> $U$ is isomorphic to an affine variety $\iff$ $\dim X=n-1$